# Nodejs Using domain.dispose() causes server to respond with status 0

Tags: node.js

When I use domain.dispose() in Node.js expressjs based HTTP Server, the client making HTTP sees a response code of 0 (Could not get any response). If I remove domain.dispose() I receive 500 error with the desired error message. Below is my code

```
//Enable domains
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  var createDomain = require('domain').create;
  var domain = createDomain();
  domain.add(req);
  domain.add(res);
  domain.run(function() {
    next();
  });
  domain.on('error', function(e) {
    //no further domain watch required
    domain.dispose(); //if I remove this line status code of 500 is received on client, otherwise 0 or no response is received
    next(e);
  });
});

//Respond with 500 for Unhandled errors
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // If the error object doesn't exists
    if (!err) return next();

    // Log it
    req.log.error(err);
    //console.error(err.stack);

    try{
    if(req.path && req.path.indexOf('/api/') === 0){
        if(!res.headersSent){
            console.log('responded with an error');
            res.status(500).send({error: err.message});
            console.log('responded with an error ACK');
        }
        return;
    }

      // Error page
    res.status(500).render('500', {
        error: err.stack
    });
    } catch(ex){
      console.log('An error occured while responding 500');
      req.log.error(ex);
    }
});
```

Can anyone explain this or a better solution? Removing domain.dispose() may cause further exceptions, which may cause to re-enter the domain, and I do want to acknowledge client with the exception message as in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour of domains. Since you have explicitly added `req` and `res` to domain, so they are disposed as well. Don't use `dispose`, it does unexpected things. When you catch an error with domain the only sensible thing to do is to shutdown the process as quickly as possible.

Comment: Does it mean that if req and res are disposed, the associated socket also gets closed?